# Declare variable length array using the array container in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

Is it possible to declare a variable length array using the array container declared in the `<array>` header and if so how to declare it in (VS) C++?

Comment: What is your actual problem that you think this might solve?

Comment: The problem of declaring variable length array using the container mentioned above. Searched a lot and hardly any resources online explicitly says it can not be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::array` is a **fixed-length** array, and its length must be known at *compile-time* as it is a parameter of the template, and thus must be a constant value.

You want `std::vector` in the `<vector>` header.  It is a **variable-length** array, its length is specified at *run-time*, and it can be resized dynamically.

Comment: "fixed-length" is very confusing. there are containers like std::valarray that are runtime-sized/non-resizable, hence also "fixed-length".

Comment: `std::valarray` is not fixed-length. It is both runtime-sized AND resizable (it has a `resize()` method). Besides, the question was specifically about `std:array`.